# Azure stream analytics query with ML function is not saving data to table storage

Tags: azure, azure-machine-learning-service, azure-stream-analytics

I have a stream analytics job in azure is integrated with Machine Learning(ML). 
I want store the data to a table in storage. My query is:

```
WITH machinelearning
     AS (SELECT 
             [IoTHub].[ConnectionDeviceId] AS [DeviceId]
           , [ventEnqueuedUtcTime]
           , [temperature]
           , [humidity]
           , [machinelearning]([temperature], [humidity]) AS [result]
         FROM [MachineLearningInput])

     SELECT 
         [System].Timestamp time
       , [DeviceId]
       , [EventEnqueuedUtcTime]
       , CAST([result].[temperature] AS FLOAT) AS [temperature]
       , CAST([result].[humidity] AS FLOAT) AS [humidity]
       , CAST([result].[Scored Probabilities] AS FLOAT) AS 'probabalities of rain'
     INTO 
         [MachineLearningOutput]
     FROM [machinelearning];
```

Without the function **machinelearning(temperature, humidity)** this query works fine.

Comment: It is working if i choose BlobStorage instead of table Storage

Comment: Please format the query, your question is hard to read

Comment: sorry about that.

Comment: It is weird, I would expect the same query to work the same way with both Blob Storage and Azure Table. Can you look at the activity log to see if there is any runtime error?